# iOS Framework and duplicated librairies

Tags: ios, compiler-construction, frameworks, code-duplication

I'm currently developing a framework which integrates SBJson inside.
So I have a blahblah.framework, and put it in my project.
But in my project I'm also using SBJson ; so the compilator says "duplicated symbols".
I would like to avoid refactoring the SBJson files into the framework, is there any other way to avoid duplicated sources ?

Thank you

Comment: you are adding it twice and then asking how to avoid duplications?

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you remove the SBJson framework you just added if its already there?
Xcode cant build class files with the same name.

Comment: Yep, you only need one copy.